# Split String not Meeting Conditions [Swift]

Tags: if-statement, swift, split

I'm trying to take a series of numbers from a text file and based on the numbers define a new variable. When I print SettingsArray i get the following:

[10, 25, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0.02, 0.002, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 25, 500, 0, 1, 250, 250, 250, 500, 500, 500, 10, 10, 10, 200, 200, 200]

Which are the numbers I'm looking for, but for some reason, when checking the If statements, all of the SettingsArray elements look something like this:

[2] String  class name = _TtC10Foundation15_NSOpaqueString

Which obviously don't meet any of the conditions, why are the array elements garbled when checking the If statements?

```
let file = String(contentsOfFile: "/Users/UserGoesHere/Documents/Settings.txt", encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)!
        var SettingsArray = split(file) {$0 == ","}
        var StepPortInvert = ""
        if SettingsArray[2] == "1" && SettingsArray[3] == "1" && SettingsArray[4] == "1" {
            var StepPortInvert = "00000000"
        }
        if SettingsArray[2] == "0" && SettingsArray[3] == "1" && SettingsArray[4] == "1" {
            var StepPortInvert = "00000001"
        }
        if SettingsArray[2] == "1" && SettingsArray[3] == "0" && SettingsArray[4] == "1" {
            var StepPortInvert = "00000010"
        }
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `NSJSONSerialisation`?

Comment: Can you specify the language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to declare StepPortInvert once. BTW 2,3,4 = "1, 0, 0"

```
let file = String(contentsOfFile: "/Users/UserGoesHere/Documents/Settings.txt", encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)!
        var SettingsArray = split(file) {$0 == ","}
        var StepPortInvert = ""
        if SettingsArray[2] == "1" && SettingsArray[3] == "1" && SettingsArray[4] == "1" {
            StepPortInvert = "00000000"
        }
        if SettingsArray[2] == "0" && SettingsArray[3] == "1" && SettingsArray[4] == "1" {
            StepPortInvert = "00000001"
        }
        if SettingsArray[2] == "1" && SettingsArray[3] == "0" && SettingsArray[4] == "1" {
            StepPortInvert = "00000010"
        }
```

Comment: Your conditions will never be true

Comment: You're right, that's all it took. It's because I originally didn't declare the empty variable but I realized I needed it for the function to accept the return. Thanks for catching that though!